# Conditional Formatting with Unequal Row Elements

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel table. I want to highlight the rows in which at least one element is different from the others for a given row. How can I do that? An example:

```
 PRODUCT         COLUMN 1   COLUMN 2     COLUMN 3
 Product 1       2,080.30    2,070.00    2,080.30
 Product 2       2,728.20    2,728.20    2,728.20
 Product 3       3.50        3.50        3.50
 Product 4       1,720.00    1,720.00    1,720.00
 Product 5       513.50      513.50      513.50
```

Row 1 will be highlighted.

Thanks

Comment: highlight duplicates

Comment: I do not want to highlight duplicates. I want to highlight rows where at least one cell is different from the other. If we have a row of three distinct elements that means I need to highlight that row (those are not duplicates).

Comment: What have you tried already? Where are you stuck? Why not highlight duplicates then sort by color to identify non duplicates?

Comment: I just found the answer @http://superuser.com/a/721122. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a slightly different approach to those suggested in the link, a bit simpler I think

If your data is in columns B,C and D starting at row 2 then I would select the whole range and apply this formula in conditional formatting

`=OR(B2<>C2,C2<>D2)`

Comment: Thanks @barry-houdini. I just tried it now. It works perfectly and it is simpler.